# How can I get company accounts in osclass

Tags: php, mysql, osclass

My question is how can I get **company accounts** in osclass 
[https://osclass.org](https://osclass.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//connect with database
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (!$link) 
{
    // can't connect to database
    $counter_connected = false;
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

//write sql query 
$sql = "SELECT pk_i_id FROM oc_t_user WHERE b_company = 1";
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$res = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $users_id[] = 'fk_i_user_id = ' .$row['pk_i_id'];
    }

    $cond = implode($users_id, ' OR ');

    //if you have country session (optional)
    if(empty($_SESSION['_country'])){
        $_SESSION['_country'] = 'SY';
    }

    $sql = "SELECT u.pk_i_id AS id, r.pk_i_id AS img_id, u.i_price, d.s_title, u.fk_c_currency_code, l.fk_c_country_code
            FROM oc_t_item u, oc_t_item_description d, oc_t_item_resource r, oc_t_item_location l
            WHERE d.fk_c_locale_code = '".osc_current_user_locale()."'
            AND ( ".$cond." )
            AND l.fk_c_country_code = '".strtoupper($_SESSION['_country'])."'
            AND l.fk_i_item_id = u.pk_i_id
            AND r.fk_i_item_id = u.pk_i_id
            AND d.fk_i_item_id = u.pk_i_id
            GROUP BY u.pk_i_id
            ORDER BY u.pk_i_id DESC
            LIMIT 12 ";
    //get the final results of all conditions    
    $users = mysqli_query($link, $sql);    
}
```